# How to update the results of a function into a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I want to multiply each element of a dictionary by items from a given list and store the result in another dictionary, with the first dictionary's keys serving as the keys in the second dictionary. The result, however, contains an error in that the product of the last item in the dictionary overwrites the product results of the previous product. View the code below for a better understanding:

```
def mult(num, x):
  return num * x

num = {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}
x = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
r = dict()
resu = dict()

for k, n in num.items():
  for i in x:
    prod = mult(n, i)
    r[i] = prod
  resu[k] = r

resu
```

The following is the output I'm getting:

```
{'one': {11: 33, 12: 36, 13: 39, 14: 42, 15: 45, 16: 48, 17: 51},
 'two': {11: 33, 12: 36, 13: 39, 14: 42, 15: 45, 16: 48, 17: 51},
 'three': {11: 33, 12: 36, 13: 39, 14: 42, 15: 45, 16: 48, 17: 51}}
```

The expected result should be like:

```
{'one': {11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17},
  'two': {11: 22, 12: 24, 13: 26, 14: 28, 15: 30, 16: 32, 17: 34},
  'three': {11: 33, 12: 36, 13: 39, 14: 42, 15: 45, 16: 48, 17: 51}}
```

Is there anyone who can assist me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're using the same dictionary `r` each time through the loop. Put `r = dict()` inside the loop.

Comment: Or just use a dictionary comprehension. `r = {i: mult(n, i) for i in x}`

Comment: And you can use a comprehension for `resu` as well: `resu = {k: {i: mult(n, i) for i in x} for k, n in num.items()}`

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks it has worked.